# How to compile openssl natively - custom version in yocto?

Tags: yocto

I am trying to add the recipe in the yocto to build openssl natively i.e for my host machine - X86.
Here is my recipe and my compilation is failing saying circular dependencies. I am unsure what to do next.

Here is the recipe -

openssl_git.bb

```
DESCRIPTION = "Potluck with different functions for different purposes that can be shared among C programs"
HOMEPAGE = "https://github.com/openssl/openssl"
LICENSE = "Apache License 2.0"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE;md5=c75985e733726beaba57bc5253e96d04"

#inherit cmake pkgconfig
SRC_URI = "git://github.com/openssl/openssl.git"
SRCREV = "${AUTOREV}"
S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

do_configure () {
    cd ${S}
    ./config
}

do_compile () {
    # Build openssl
    oe_runmake -C ${S}
}

BBCLASSEXTEND += "native"
```

Here is the build error -

```
    arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-m64'
| arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-m64'
| Makefile:3979: recipe for target 'apps/lib/libapps-lib-app_params.o' failed
| make[1]: *** [apps/lib/libapps-lib-app_params.o] Error 1
| make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
| Makefile:3987: recipe for target 'apps/lib/libapps-lib-app_provider.o' failed
| make[1]: *** [apps/lib/libapps-lib-app_provider.o] Error 1
| arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-m64'
| Makefile:3995: recipe for target 'apps/lib/libapps-lib-app_rand.o' failed
| make[1]: *** [apps/lib/libapps-lib-app_rand.o] Error 1
| arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-m64'
| Makefile:4003: recipe for target 'apps/lib/libapps-lib-app_x509.o' failed
| make[1]: *** [apps/lib/libapps-lib-app_x509.o] Error 1
| make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/user/temp/custom_yocto/build-custom-zynq/tmp/work/cortexa9t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/openssl/git-r0/git'
| Makefile:3055: recipe for target 'build_sw' failed
```

Comment: Why not storing the patches of what you would like to change in the openssl code in a own meta-layer and add a openssl.bbappend to it?

Comment: openssl in oe-core can already be built for native so this does not seem useful. As vermaete says, the normal way to modify the openssl build would be to add a bbappend in your layer. If you really want a new openssl recipe, you should at least start with a copy of the one in oe-core and save yourself loads of extremely tricky packaging work.

Comment: I am trying to build it for my host machine and not for my target.